# MYSQL Ordering For a Train Timetable PHP Over Midnight

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to order sets of train timetables by their departure times from stations but the problem occurs when a train passes over midnight.

Below is an example of the data flowing into my mysql database. For a given train schedule I have its basic route and basic departure times from each station (Marked by the y under sche). Every now and then I may also receive an update of amended departure times for a given train schedule.

In its self the above is not a problem as I order my data based on the timeref. However my problem comes when a train passes midnight. This is because the times I receive are in pure 24hr format - ie 01:00

```
Count   Location       Trainid      Timeref     Sche     Update

  1      London          t256         22:10        y
  2      Cricklewood     t256         23:00        y
  3      Luton           t256         01:00        y 
  4      Leicester       t256         02:00        y
  5      Doncaster       r659         06:00                 y
  6      Luton           t256         01:10                 y
  7      Sheffield       y783         05:00                 y
```

I want to show the data as below (in that order). ie in the order of the original timetable but with an updated time for Luton to 01:10

```
 London        t256      22:10
 Cricklewood   t256      23:00 
 Luton         t256      01:10
 Leicester     t256      02:00
```

My below code works fine except where a train crosses midnight

```
 $stmt3=$mysql_link->prepare("SELECT count,trainid,location,timeref,sche,update FROM (SELECT count,trainid,location,timeref,sche,update FROM darwinall WHERE trainid=:trainid ORDER BY count DESC) as temp GROUP BY location ORDER BY timeref ASC");
              $stmt3->execute(array(':trainid'=>$trainid));
 foreach($stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row3) {
 echo result.................
 }
```

So instead of the above I get the following result, which is wrong

```
Luton         t256      01:10
Leicester     t256      02:00
London        t256      22:10
Cricklewood   t256      23:00
```

Comment: Doest the `count` value mean anything? It seems to me the database is missing crucial information about the order of the stops and that will lead to unexpected bugs.

Comment: The count is the order the messages are received in. However I do know the original timetable running order (if that helps). Its marked with the y under sche. So I know the order of stations

Comment: There is no order in a database unless you order by one (or more...) of the columns. I also don't know what *messages* means. What if someone enters a new route, forgets a stop and ads it later; your whole system collapses.

Comment: @jeroen It looks to me like `Count` is just an auto-incremented ID field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put all times between midnight and 6am after other times, you can do:

```
ORDER BY timeref < '06:00', timeref
```

Comment: I also have many train schedules where trains start at say 02:00 and run calling at stations up to say 23:00. If I use the above code I think it will put those the wrong way around. ie it will correct my first problem and then cause another?

Comment: So how is it supposed to know whether to put 02:00 at the begining or the end of the list? You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Agreed. The info I do know is that I do have the orginal schedule - ie in the above example I do have the running order of the train . ie marked with the y above under sche

Comment: I don't see how that helps. The original time for Luton was 01:00, the updated time is 01:10. They're both early morning, so they'll be in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you could use is to to check the current time, and first order all the `timeref`s after it (i.e., today's trains) and only then the `timeref`s before it (i.e., post-midnight):

```
SELECT    `count`, trainid, location, timeref, sche, `update` 
FROM      (SELECT   `count`, trainid, location, timeref, sche, `update` 
           FROM     darwinall 
           WHERE    trainid=:trainid 
           ORDER BY `count` DESC) AS temp 
GROUP BY location 
ORDER BY timeref < CURRENT_TIME() ASC, timeref ASC
```

BTW: `count` and `update` are reserved words, you should probably protect them with backticks.

Comment: Those are backticks, not forward quotes.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik. Interesting idea. Just playing with that

Comment: Gave uptick for reserved word comments